# Trading after the close

Tags: equities, quant-trading-strategies

Are there institutions that will fill stock trades after the close (from stock on their order book) at the official close price? If so, would it be significantly more expensive to execute a trade this way than to send a market-on-close order to the same institution?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the liquidity disappears after close, so for that reason alone it is more expensive. The spread is much wider.

To find someone willing to trade on the close price after close is the same thing as trying to find someone willing to trade on the price from 1 pm at 2 pm.

Answer (score 0):

After NYSE close and also before open, you may be able to trade on [NYSE Arca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NYSE_Arca), but not at any closing price. As the news come in and markets move, the prices move on Arca. (If the price after 4pm moves in your favor, but you still insist on executing at the 4pm close, you should be able to find someone, but I don't think this platform would let you.)